# Printing several pieces of output to the same CSV in R?

Tags: r, csv, file-io, traminer

I am using the TraMineR package. I am printing output to a CSV file, like this:

```
write.csv(seqient(sequences.seq), file = "diversity_measures.csv", quote = FALSE, na = "", row.names = TRUE)
write.csv(seqici(sequences.seq), file = "diversity_measures.csv", quote = FALSE, na = "", row.names = TRUE, append= TRUE)
write.csv(seqST(sequences.seq), file = "diversity_measures.csv", quote = FALSE, na = "", row.names = TRUE,  append= TRUE)
```

The dput(sequences.seq) object can be found [here](https://github.com/aronlindberg/VOSS-Sequencing-Toolkit/blob/master/rubinius_rubinius_sequencing/sequences.seq_object).

However, this does not append the output properly but creates this error message:

```
In write.csv(seqST(sequences.seq), file = "diversity_measures.csv",  :attempt to set 'append' ignored
```

Additionally, it only gives me the output for the last command, so it seems like it overwrites the file each time.

Is it possible to get all the columns in a single CSV file, with a column name for each (i.e. entropy, complexity, turbulence)

Comment: The tag "traminer" would be appropriate to this post, but it is not available. There are 18 questions on stats.SE on traminer, and some of them could be suitable here. Hence, I recommend creating the tag "traminer"

Comment: You can use `append=TRUE`. or write out `data.frame(entropy=seqient(sequences.seq), complexity=seqici(sequences.seq), turbulence=seqST(sequences.seq))`.

Comment: I tried append=TRUE, but it just overwrites my file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `append=TRUE` in `write.table` calls and use the same file name, but you'll need to specify all the other arguments as needed.  `append=TRUE` is not available for the wrapper function `write.csv`, as noted in the documentation:

> These wrappers are deliberately inflexible: they are designed to
>   ensure that the correct conventions are used to write a valid file.
>   Attempts to change append, col.names, sep, dec or qmethod are ignored,
>   with a warning.

Or you could write out

```
write.csv(data.frame(entropy=seqient(sequences.seq), 
                     complexity=seqici(sequences.seq), 
                     turbulence=seqST(sequences.seq)),
          'output.csv')
```